# How to get id of a div onclick of it.?

Tags: javascript

I have three Divs like    < /div>.. There is a function onclick of first div.. I have to put one condition so that remaining  code should not executed if it contains second Divs id

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using

```
$("div:first").click(function()
{
  console.log("clicked first div");
}
```